# client side server within the browser?

Tags: javascript, sockets, client-side, p2p

would it be possible to code an browser independent client-side server within the browser. I looked for an javascript solution but its not possible to open a socket. Is it possible with other standards or "reuse" the browser-socket? I am looking for a way to load content from another website - but there is always this "same domain-only"-policy.

There are a few p2p-social networks - how do they work?

Quick and dirty: Is it possible to load data from a different domain without a proxy to preserve the users ip/host-identification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few leads on technologies that might help from the server side:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

In particular, long-polling allows you to keep a continuous connection to the server to relay information.

You might also want to look into HTML5 WebSockets.

Using these technologies, you could set something up like a list of servers that can relay client updates to the network.

Comment: I want to load files from another domain, but without a proxy indirection - is this somehow possible?

Comment: You can load "files" (per se) but you'll need to use the appropriate methods for certain content.

Here is some information on the new XMLHTTPRequest and how it works with CORS -
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Answer (score 0):

If compatibility isn't an issue, you might take a look at [websockets](http://websocket.org/) in the HTML5 spec. Of course, any client-side solution will only work in browsers that support it!

Most of the P2P clients you see are either interfacing with a server via AJAX or using some third-party plugin (often Java) to establish the connection outside of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Flash](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html) to do it